# How to not add Null to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

If `null` is entered as a parameter it is not suppose to be added to the arrayList I am using BlueJ compiler and I have tried coding this a few ways but still not working.

Here are my methods:

```
public void addLamborghini(Lamborghini newLamborghini)
{
   if(newLamborghini ==null){
     return; // do not store
   }
   if(newLamborghini.equals(newLamborghini)){
     inventory.add(newLamborghini);
   }
}
```

also tried this way:

```
public void addLamborghini(Lamborghini newLamborghini)
{

   if(newLamborghini ==null){
      return; // do not store
   }
   else if(newLamborghini.equals(newLamborghini)){
      inventory.add(newLamborghini);
   }
}
```

also tried this:

```
public void addLamborghini(Lamborghini newLamborghini)
{
    if(newLamborghini !=null){
        inventory.add(newLamborghini);
    }
}
```

also tried it with the arrayList loop:

```
public void addLamborghini(Lamborghini newLamborghini)
{
    for(Lamborghini l : inventory){

      if(newLamborghini ==null){
        return; // do not store
      }
     inventory.add(newLamborghini);
   }
}
```

also tried this:

```
public void addLamborghini(Lamborghini newLamborghini)
{
    for(Lamborghini l : inventory){

     if(newLamborghini ==null){
        continue; // do not store
     }
     inventory.add(newLamborghini);
   }
}
```

and tried this:

```
  public void addLamborghini(Lamborghini newLamborghini)
  {
       if(newLamborghini ==null){
         inventory.remove(null); // do not store
       }
       if(newLamborghini == newLamborghini){
        inventory.add(newLamborghini);
       }
   }
```

I believe I have exhausted all the methods I can think of and have done research online but can't seem to find a valid answer to my question.  The methods above will either add null or it will not add null and not add a new car parameter that is not null.  Can't seem to figure out how to not allow null to be added to the ArrayList.

If anyone can help me code this it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Here are my requirements:

```
public void  addLamborghini(Lamborghini newLamborghini)
```

- adds a new Lamborghini to the inventory
- if the newLamborghini parameter is null, it is not added to the inventory.

Comment: Your first three bits of code look like they shouldn't add nulls. How do you know you have nulls? Try doing a `System.put.println("Adding: " + newLamborghini);` before your `inventory.add()` and see if it ever adds a null.

Comment: the first method should works, if it not maybe you should check your input arraylist but not your current method, how you confirm it is null, maybe you should override `Lamborghini ` class toString method and check out whether null is true.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, this methode should work:

```
public void addLamborghini(Lamborghini newLamborghini)
{

    if(newLamborghini !=null){
        inventory.add(newLamborghini);

    }

}
```

Are you sure that the problem does not reside in another part of your code? Also, if you could provide us with more information. Like an example of a Lamborghini that you create, add and the following result in your inventory.